# Map all requests to HttpHandler

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

I want to map EVERY request to an HttpHandler called RequestHandler.

I have this in my Web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
  <add verb="*" path="*" type="WebApplication1.RequestHandler" />
</httpHandlers>
```

My problem is that IIS stop requests before they get to my application. What should I put in the IIS config to forward all requests to this handler?

Comment: Do you want this to be the *only* handler?

Comment: Yes. Or at the very least the default fallback handler.